# JHipster context path with two slashes

Tags: java, reactjs, jhipster, contextpath

Anybody know how a context path can be added with two slashes like /app/idontknow to a JHipster generated application that uses React?
Setting the value for "servlet.context-path" in the application-dev.yaml file in combination with setting the value for "base" in webpack.common.js does not work.

However, when setting the path with only one forward slash (/app_idontknow) it works.

Comment: With Angular, you also need to modify the `index.html` file, change `<base href="/" />` to something like `<base href="/idontknow/" />`.  Also, call the JAR with the following options: `java -jar idontknow.jar --server.servlet.context-path=/idontknow`  I don't know if the same applies to React...

Comment: No, index.html file is not necessary with React.

Comment: Part of the solution is that the servlet context path setting must end with a slash like /dir1/dir2/ and not /dir1/dir. Using this improves the misbehavior but does not lead to solve all problems.